# Type D visa holder, travel outside of the EU

Tags: visas, schengen, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, long-stay-visas

I have a type D visa, but it is valid for Germany. I will travel to my country (outside of the EU) and I will come back passing through Spain (I will stay a while between flights because I have booked with two different companies). Will Spain allow me to pass through? Can anyone confirm if I can, please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is your D visa still valid

Comment: Yes, it is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your D visa is still valid, then you can exit and re-enter the Schengen Area through Spain.

While it says it's only valid for one country (I really don't know why - it's stupid), since a couple of years they've been equal to residence permits in normal cases, permitting entry and exit to/from the Area through any member state.

Comment: D visa must mention the one country where 90/180 does *not* apply. A D visa which explicitly excludes travel to other countries would be unusual.